How to traverse from an starting node in DBpedia sparql?
I have an starting page in dbpedia(https://dbpedia.org/page/Hassan_Rouhani) and I want to traverse his graph only using some specific properties(like dbo:party or dbp:office) until ith depth. I also want to record the connections between entities so i can visualize the graph later. I'm not that skilled in sparql so i'd aprreciate if you can help me.
This is the query that I wrote:
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

CONSTRUCT {
  ?entity ?property ?target
}
WHERE {
  {
    <https://dbpedia.org/page/Hassan_Rouhani> ?property ?entity .
    FILTER(?property IN (dbo:party, dbp:office))
    OPTIONAL { ?entity ?property ?target . }
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?entity ?property ?target .
    FILTER(?property IN (dbo:party, dbp:office))
    OPTIONAL { ?target ?property ?next . }
  }
}
LIMIT 100


are you sure that the data provides paths along dbo:party or dbp:office proeprties? I mean, a party assigns a party y to a person x, and then the only thing I can see is an office assigned to the party y. Or is there any party that also has a party attached? Vice versa for office

that said, SPARQL 1.1 has no built-in syntactic sugar to limit the path depth. you can indeed use property paths and if you know the max depth simply repeat an optional pattern. Something like (dbo:party|dbp:office)/(dbo:party|dbp:office)? would emulate a path of max depth 2. keeping track of the edges needs an intermediate node via another triple pattern before the property path pattern
